# Twitter widget on Blogger - either turns up on all pages or none at all. WHY?

Tags: html, twitter, widget, hide, blogger

I want only one of my pages to display the Twitter list widget in the sidebar.(BLOGGER).
Designer Template.

My code is below :-

```
        <b:widget id='HTML4' locked='false' title='Twitter' type='HTML'>
        <b:includable id='main'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;http://tfi-alumni-impact.blogspot.in/p/mouthpiece.html&quot; '>
        <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
        <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
        <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
        </b:if>
        <div class='widget-content'>
         <data:content/>
        </div>
        <b:include name='quickedit'/>
       </b:if>
       </b:includable>
       </b:widget

>
```

But, as you can see on the blog; IT DOES NOT APPEAR ON THE RIGHT SIDEBAR. 
I have edited the html of the page : -

```
<style type='text/css'>
#HTML1, #Slideshow1, #Image1, #Poll1, #HTML2, #HTML1 { display:none !important;}
</style>
```

But I don't think that's the problem.
What have I done wrong/What can i do to achieve my aim?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you closing your widget tag? and what `display: none;` is for? if you are using it for this widget it'll hide your widget..oh I see `display: none;` doesn't hold HTML4 id of this widget so no problem, but 1 more thing you are using `#HTML1` twice in your CSS

Comment: Yes, I dunno why but using HTML1 just once to hide it was ineffective. yes, sorry didn't copy it properly - I am closing my widget tag.